# Kotlin: Equivalent of getClass() for KClass

Tags: java, class, kotlin

In Java we can resolve a variable's class through `getClass()` like `something.getClass()`. In Kotlin I am aware of `something.javaClass` which is nice but I want to be able to get the `KClass` in a similar way. I've seen the `Something::class` syntax but this is not what I need. I need to get the KClass of a variable. Does such functionality exist?

Answer (score 239, accepted):

The easiest way to achieve this since Kotlin 1.1 is the [class reference syntax](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/reflection.html#bound-class-references-since-11):

```
something::class
```

If you use Kotlin 1.0, you can convert the obtained Java class to a KClass instance by calling the `.kotlin` extension property:

```
something.javaClass.kotlin
```

Comment: Any place I can follow the implementation of something::class?

Comment: @Nishad The easiest place would be to look at the generated bytecode (e.g. with `javap`)

Comment: You can also use `KClass::class` to get the current class object.

Comment: Something to note is that `something::class` returns `KClass<out Something>` while `something.javaClass.kotlin` returns `KClass<Something>`

Comment: @SamindaPeramuna This is just wrong, KClass::class returns the class object kotlin.reflect.KClass not the current class object! To get it you have to use this::class.

Comment: Just use ```something::class.simplename```

Answer (score 14):

*EDIT: See comments, below, and answer from Alexander, above. This advice was originally for Kotlin 1.0 and it seems is now obsolete.*

Since the language doesn't support a direct way to get this yet, [consider defining an extension method for now](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/extensions.html).

```
fun<T: Any> T.getClass(): KClass<T> {
    return javaClass.kotlin
}

val test = 0
println("Kotlin type: ${test.getClass()}")
```

Or, if you prefer a property:

```
val<T: Any> T.kClass: KClass<T>
    get() = javaClass.kotlin

val test = 0
println("Kotlin type: ${test.kClass}")
```

Comment: You can skip the `java` bit and go straight Kotlin: `fun<T: Any> T.getClass(): KClass<out T> = this::class`

Comment: This answer should be updated to reflect the changes in 1.1. Now it is possible to get the class using `someClass::class`

Answer (score 14):

Here's my solution

```
val TAG = javaClass.simpleName
```

With javaClass.simpleName you can obtain your class name. Also the above example is very useful for android developers to declare on top of the class as an instance variable for logging purposes.

Answer (score 4):

I think this is the better solution.
Found here https://www.techiedelight.com/determine-class-name-in-kotlin/

```
fun main() {
    val s = "Kotlin"
    println(s::class)                           // class kotlin.String
    println(s::class.qualifiedName)             // kotlin.String
    println(s::class.simpleName)                // String
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 3):

Since Kotlin 1.5.21 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.5.21)

`val TAG = javaClass.simpleName will work no more!`

Error "Not enough information to infer type variable T"

```kotlin
/**
 * Returns the runtime Java class of this object.
 */
public inline val <T : Any> T.javaClass: Class<T>
    @Suppress("UsePropertyAccessSyntax")
    get() = (this as java.lang.Object).getClass() as Class<T>

@Deprecated("Use 'java' property to get Java class corresponding to this Kotlin class or cast this instance to Any if you really want to get the runtime Java class of this implementation of KClass.", ReplaceWith("(this as Any).javaClass"), level = DeprecationLevel.ERROR)
public inline val <T : Any> KClass<T>.javaClass: Class<KClass<T>>
    @JvmName("getRuntimeClassOfKClassInstance")
    @Suppress("UsePropertyAccessSyntax")
    get() = (this as java.lang.Object).getClass() as Class<KClass<T>>
```

You can try now
`YourClassName::class.java.simpleName`

Answer (score 2):

**Here are different Implementations to get class names. You can utilize it as per your requirements.**

```
import kotlin.reflect.KClass

val <T : Any > T.kClassName: KClass<out T>
get() {
    return javaClass.kotlin
}
```

**Here we can get the class name in kotlin**

```
val <T : Any > T.classNameKotlin: String?
get() {
    return javaClass.kotlin.simpleName
}
```

**Here we can get the class name in kotlin**

```
val <T : Any > T.classNameJava: String
get() {
    return javaClass.simpleName
}
```

**Here are the outputs to the following operations.**

```
fun main(){

val userAge = 0

println(userAge.kClassName) 
Output: class java.lang.Integer (Kotlin reflection is not available)

println(userAge.classNameKotlin)
Output: Int

println(userAge.classNameJava)
Output: Integer
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In Kotlin:

```
val className = serviceClass.javaClass.name
```